# SSJS activities: Clear Data from Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, ssjs

I am trying to write a code in SSJS to clear all data in a Data Extensions
Below a sample code

```
    <script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("core","1");

    var CAMPAGNE= DataExtension.Init("CLIENTI_INSERITI_IN_CAMPAGNA");

   CAMPAGNE.Rows.Remove(["PK_CONTATTI_MC"],["4672248"]);
   CAMPAGNE.Rows.Remove(["PK_CONTATTI_MC"],["1112223"]);

</script>
```

As you can see I delete the single rows....but I'd like to delete all DE.

How can I you achieve this ?

Regards
Riccardo Pruner

Answer (score 4):

Use the [DeleteData or DeleteDE](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/interacting_with_data_extensions_using_the_function_object/) functions from Platform functions.  These functions are for deleting mass amounts of data from a Data Extension, the Rows.Remove is more for use with manipulating a single row.

> **DeleteData(S1,A1,A2)**
>
> Use this method to delete information from a data
>   extension as indicated by the array containing the listed column name
>   and value pairs. You can include multiple column name and value pairs
>   in a single call. You can use this method in non-sending contexts,
>   such as landing pages. This call returns the number of rows modified.
>
> Arguments
>
> S1 - String value indicating the name of the data extension
>
> A1 - Array
>   containing the names of the columns from the data extension
>
> A2 - Array
>   containing the relevant values in the data extension
>
> Example
>
> ```
> <script runat="server">
>       var rows = Platform.Function.DeleteData('CustomerData',['LastName'],['Smith']);
>  </script>
> ```
>
> This example deletes the rows from the data extension with
>   the LastName value of Smith.
>
> **DeleteDE(S1,A1,A2)**
>
> Use this method to delete information from a data
>   extension as indicated by the array containing the listed column name
>   and value pairs. You can include multiple column name and value pairs
>   in a single call. You can use this method in sendable contexts, such
>   as email messages.
>
> Arguments
>
> S1 - String value indicating the name of the data extension
>
> A1 - Array
>   containing the names of the columns from the data extension
>
> A2 - Array
>   containing the relevant values in the data extension
>
> Example
>
> ```
> <script runat="server">
>   var rows = Platform.Function.DeleteDE('CustomerData',['LastName'],['Smith']);
> </script>
> ```
>
> This example deletes the rows from the data extension with
>   the LastName value of Smith.

Comment: Thanks so much.
I read this documentation but I should insert a sort of filter to select a specific rows and delete. Otherwise I'd like delete All records in a DE less use a filter.

Comment: add a field named 'secret' to your DE and have all values '1'  (can set default value as well so that any time you import into it, it automatically adds the 1 on).  This way you can have the filter on that field and value which will delete all

Comment: Understand! 
Thanks you so much ;)

Comment: If you need it without a filter, you can do it via an API call (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/clearing_data_from_a_data_extension/)

Comment: Can be completed with WSproxy now. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/249181/65280

Comment: Could one also use conditions instead of specifying values? E.g. Could one delete all rows with a value of "LastUpdated" column older than 30 days?