# Refreshing a filtered Data Extension with SOAP via wsproxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

There is a rather limited documentation for wsproxy when it comes to the performitem function:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_perform.htm

for example, there is the action "ClearData" to clear a DE as desribed here:
[Clearing a Data Extension using SSJS with SOAP](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242683/clearing-a-data-extension-using-ssjs-with-soap/249181)

I am looking for a way to refresh a filtered DE via wsproxy - is there a specific action I could use for this?

Comment: If you are okay to use REST API... then here is the usefull article from Salesforce MVP @Gortonington ....https://gortonington.com/refresh-a-filtered-data-extension-via-rest-api/

Comment: As a note, I do not believe this is possible via SOAP without utilizing 'Filter Activity' (from Automation Studio) and not directly to an existing filtered DE.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); 
var props = {
    CustomerKey: "FILTER_EXTERNAL_KEY"
}
var action = "Start";
var opts = {};
var result = prox.performItem("FilterActivity", props, action, opts);
</script>
```